# unable to read first line of data after extracting data from text file c program

Tags: c

after reading my text file, i put the 100x10 array of data into datafile[100][10].

afterwards, i want to split the data into 4 different arrays called traininginput[90][9], trainingoutput[10][1], testinput[10][9], and testoutput[10][1].

i did transferring/copying of data from filedata[][] into trainininput[][] using a for loop as so.

i tried to print afterwards to test if the datas are copied over. but the first line of data was displayed wrongly.

```
int main()
{
    float traininginput[90][9], trainingoutput[90][1], testinput[10][9], testoutput[10][1], filedata[100][10];
    int i,j,k;

    FILE *file_ptr;
    file_ptr = fopen("fertility_data.txt", "r");

    if ( file_ptr == NULL )   //if cant read file, exit
    {
        printf("Error reading File!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i=0; i<100; i++)
    {  
        fscanf(file_ptr,"%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f",&filedata[i][0],&filedata[i][1],&filedata[i][2],&filedata[i][3],&filedata[i][4],&filedata[i][5],&filedata[i][6],&filedata[i][7],&filedata[i][8],&filedata[i][9]); 
    }
    fclose(file_ptr);
    

    for(i=0;i<90;i++) //training input
    {
        for(j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            traininginput[i][j]=filedata[i][j];
        }
    }


    for(i=0;i<90;i++)   //testing to see output from file and into array
    {
        for(j=0;j<90;j++)
        {
            printf("%f ",traininginput[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

text file data (only first few lines and columns for illustration purposes, last column is not needed) :

```
-0.33,0.5,1,1,0,-1,0.8,0,0.88,1

0.33,0.69,1,0,0,1,1,-1,0.31,0

1,0.56,1,0,0,1,0.6,0,0.5,0

-1,0.5,1,0,0,1,0.8,-1,0.44,0
```

Comment: `for(j=0;j<90;j++)` looks wrong and will cause out-of-range access at `traininginput[i][j]`.

Comment: [I tried your code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4eqTfmTjZ8ygUsfj) and the first part of output looked good.